# Splitting and calling data

Tags: python

I have data from a series of points that over lap between two graphs that give the following data:
MULTIPOINT (2.143370447157314 0.1353352832366127, 75.99346394751342 0.1353352832366127, 94.39258581473268 0.1353352832366127, 111.8928901992089 0.1353352832366127, 127.0468781718633 0.1353352832366127, 184.5804306294127 0.1353352832366127, 204.2456523252587 0.1353352832366127, 219.5685478372618 0.1353352832366127, 231.2004389877476 0.1353352832366127, 293.5451724106475 0.1353352832366127, 310.9486085910552 0.1353352832366127, 330.0610044903921 0.1353352832366127, 338.7762476890871 0.1353352832366127, 402.2859828353771 0.1353352832366127, 422.3815761349065 0.1353352832366127, 440.9842862789425 0.1353352832366127, 451.6324097852983 0.1353352832366127, 512.7034613293686 0.1353352832366127, 530.623914129864 0.1353352832366127, 549.842226961968 0.1353352832366127, 561.6760004904758 0.1353352832366127, 624.6195484846207 0.1353352832366127, 640.701617729866 0.1353352832366127, 659.3176260680895 0.1353352832366127, 659.6827799404297 0.1353352832366127, 661.1778885763671 0.1353352832366127, 671.2977053828017 0.1353352832366127, 738.9468397381991 0.1353352832366127, 747.9185452191947 0.1353352832366127, 768.0657707819746 0.1353352832366127, 782.5204038757331 0.1353352832366127, 879.0203459813714 0.1353352832366127, 895.3297620941928 0.1353352832366127, 958.2812971302388 0.1353352832366127, 958.9412279666292 0.1353352832366127, 986.2760322593815 0.1353352832366127, 1001.912171992246 0.1353352832366127, 1096.858061280496 0.1353352832366127, 1118.376788346299 0.1353352832366127, 1203.92639341071 0.1353352832366127, 1220.384947439686 0.1353352832366127, 1317.401330046149 0.1353352832366127, 1317.502930130382 0.1353352832366127, 1318.858929927066 0.1353352832366127, 1319.772755799937 0.1353352832366127, 1323.478519672568 0.1353352832366127, 1325.491001741218 0.1353352832366127, 1429.099147413253 0.1353352832366127)

All of the Y values are the same and so I want to separate the X and Y values and only call the X values. I have tried using the .split function but it doesn't work. I also will have to do this with more data sets so if there's a universal way of doing it without knowing the X values that would be very helpful. Any help would be Greatly appreciated! I am using python.

here is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Kyle\\Desktop\\Plot_Values1.csv")


Distance = df['distance']
intensity = df['Gray_Value']
intensity_norm = (intensity - intensity.min())/ (intensity.max() - intensity.min())

  
x = Distance
y = intensity_norm

y2= np.full_like(intensity_norm, 1 / math.exp(2))

plt.plot(x, intensity_norm)
plt.axhline(y=1/math.exp(2), color='r', linestyle='-')


first_line = LineString(np.column_stack((x, y2)))
second_line = LineString(np.column_stack((x, y)))
intersection = first_line.intersection(second_line)

Inter = np.full_like(intersection, intersection)
```

.split(" ") to try to split by spaces.

Comment: Are you using a specific language, or do you want some sort of meta process? If you are using a specific language, add the corresponding tag to your question to increase your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: Also if you have a code sample of what you have tried, and what specifically isn't working, you should add that to the question as well. It's much easier to help if we can see what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry my first time asking a question here but I updated Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using Python.

```
str = "MULTIPOINT (2.143370447157314 0.1353352832366127, 75.99346394751342 0.1353352832366127, 94.39258581473268 0.1353352832366127, 111.8928901992089 0.1353352832366127, 127.0468781718633 0.1353352832366127, 184.5804306294127 0.1353352832366127, 204.2456523252587 0.1353352832366127, 219.5685478372618 0.1353352832366127, 231.2004389877476 0.1353352832366127, 293.5451724106475 0.1353352832366127, 310.9486085910552 0.1353352832366127, 330.0610044903921 0.1353352832366127, 338.7762476890871 0.1353352832366127, 402.2859828353771 0.1353352832366127, 422.3815761349065 0.1353352832366127, 440.9842862789425 0.1353352832366127, 451.6324097852983 0.1353352832366127, 512.7034613293686 0.1353352832366127, 530.623914129864 0.1353352832366127, 549.842226961968 0.1353352832366127, 561.6760004904758 0.1353352832366127, 624.6195484846207 0.1353352832366127, 640.701617729866 0.1353352832366127, 659.3176260680895 0.1353352832366127, 659.6827799404297 0.1353352832366127, 661.1778885763671 0.1353352832366127, 671.2977053828017 0.1353352832366127, 738.9468397381991 0.1353352832366127, 747.9185452191947 0.1353352832366127, 768.0657707819746 0.1353352832366127, 782.5204038757331 0.1353352832366127, 879.0203459813714 0.1353352832366127, 895.3297620941928 0.1353352832366127, 958.2812971302388 0.1353352832366127, 958.9412279666292 0.1353352832366127, 986.2760322593815 0.1353352832366127, 1001.912171992246 0.1353352832366127, 1096.858061280496 0.1353352832366127, 1118.376788346299 0.1353352832366127, 1203.92639341071 0.1353352832366127, 1220.384947439686 0.1353352832366127, 1317.401330046149 0.1353352832366127, 1317.502930130382 0.1353352832366127, 1318.858929927066 0.1353352832366127, 1319.772755799937 0.1353352832366127, 1323.478519672568 0.1353352832366127, 1325.491001741218 0.1353352832366127, 1429.099147413253 0.1353352832366127)"
left = str.find('(')
right = str.rfind(')')
x_list = [x.split(' ')[0] for x in str[left+1:right].split(', ')]
```

Result:

```
['2.143370447157314', '75.99346394751342', '94.39258581473268', '111.8928901992089', '127.0468781718633', '184.5804306294127', '204.2456523252587', '219.5685478372618', '231.2004389877476', '293.5451724106475', '310.9486085910552', '330.0610044903921', '338.7762476890871', '402.2859828353771', '422.3815761349065', '440.9842862789425', '451.6324097852983', '512.7034613293686', '530.623914129864', '549.842226961968', '561.6760004904758', '624.6195484846207', '640.701617729866', '659.3176260680895', '659.6827799404297', '661.1778885763671', '671.2977053828017', '738.9468397381991', '747.9185452191947', '768.0657707819746', '782.5204038757331', '879.0203459813714', '895.3297620941928', '958.2812971302388', '958.9412279666292', '986.2760322593815', '1001.912171992246', '1096.858061280496', '1118.376788346299', '1203.92639341071', '1220.384947439686', '1317.401330046149', '1317.502930130382', '1318.858929927066', '1319.772755799937', '1323.478519672568', '1325.491001741218', '1429.099147413253']
```

**EDIT:** As you appear to be using `shapely`, you can iterate through the geometry collection of the `MultiPoint` object and extract the values of `x` directly.

Example:

```
from shapely import MultiPoint
mp_obj = MultiPoint([[2.143370447157314, 0.1353352832366127], 
                     [75.99346394751342, 0.1353352832366127],
                     [94.39258581473268, 0.1353352832366127]])
xs = [p.x for p in mp_obj.geoms]
```

Result:

```
[2.143370447157314, 75.99346394751342, 94.39258581473268]
```

Comment: Thank you and yes I am using python. Is there a way to have this universal if I don't know the X coordinates

Comment: You can iterate through the collection of points in the object. I've added an example in my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much this was very helpful and worked!

Answer (score 0):

> *"... All of the Y values are the same and so I want to separate the X and Y values and only call the X values. I have tried using the .split function but it doesn't work. I also will have to do this with more data sets so if there's a universal way of doing it without knowing the X values that would be very helpful. ..."*

There are a few ways to do this.

Here is one way, with *str.split*, and a *[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?#list-comprehensions)*.

```py
y = [x[:x.find(' ')] for x in s.split(', ')]
```

You could also use the *[re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)* module, and match the values.

```py
y = [x.group() for x in re.finditer('[^, ]+(?= )', s)]
```

Or, you can utilize the *[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?#enumerate)* function to traverse the *string*.

```py
y = []
o = 0
for i, c in enumerate(s):
    if c == ' ':
        if s[i - 1] != ',': y.append(s[o:i])
        o = i + 1
```

Output, truncated.

```
2.143370447157314
75.99346394751342
94.39258581473268
...
1323.478519672568
1325.491001741218
1429.099147413253
```